# How to make a Jetpack Compose component invisible that does not superpose any other

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I have a miniplayer that becomes invisible when it is opened. The things is that i just change the Modifier.alpha but that doesn't make it untouchable, so I dont know how exactly do it. Thank you!

Here is the video of how it works now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDCYp.jpg

I wanted to make it dissapear while it's fullscreen opened. I don't really know how to do that so I have no idea from where to start to test. I tried making the Surface not clickable, but nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using AnimatedVisibility UI component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).